# How do you send another user on your domain a remote assistance invitation?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-assistance

I want to be able to jump into the same session the user is in and take control of their PC. I have enabled Remote Assistance via group policy and that is reflected on the PCs under remote settings. When I open the remote assistance program I only have the option to offer assistance **to someone who has invited me** or to invite someone. Is there a way for me to just type in an IP address or netbios name and just have a box pop up on their screen saying I want to take control? Much like RDP works... I searched around, but didn't find a good explanation of how to actually use Remote Assistance.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Windows Remote Assistance doesn't work that way. You'll need a third party software like VNC or something similar. Where I work we use Goverlan Remote Control and it does the job exactly as you described.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the Windows Remote Assistance Tool, choose the Option "Help Someone who has invited you". On the next screen instead of using the big and obvious buttons look for the text "Advanced connection options for help desk" at the very bottom of the dialog. Pressing this presents you with the option of a direct IP or Hostename connect, where the user has to accept your connection.

Alternatively you can start the program via the command

```
C:\Windows\System32\msra.exe /offerra
```

to get directly to that window.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error still, but you at least answered my question. I will look into my policy settings to make sure they are correct.

Comment: It's always hard to say which policies affect a given feature but I would see in our domain we have only enabled: "Computer Config\Administrative Templates\System\Remote Assistance\Configure Offer Remote Assistance". We have even disabled "Configure Solicited Remote Assistance" and it still works fine. The offering Computer has to be part of the domain though afaik